# How to select from table where value from another table is greather than some value?

Tags: mysql, sql

How could I select * from table `movies` where `seeds` > 10 in table `torrents`? Table `movies` has unique `id`, while table torrents has `id` that matches the movie id. There are few torrents for each movie and having just one that has seeds greather than 10 should be selected.

The only sql I have is this where it deletes all movies which don't have any torrents.

```
DELETE FROM movies WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT id FROM torrents WHERE id=movies.id)
```

I'm not good at mysql at that level to make it, even with this example, which I also got from around here.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like the following:

```
select *
from movies m
where exists (
  select * from torrents t
  where t.id = m.id and t.seeds > 10
);
```

Comment: Now that explains some things. With multiple examples I got, I was able to understand how it works and can make one myself. Thank you very much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

id from torrents where seeds > 10

```
select * from movies where movie_id in (select id from torrents where seeds > 10);
```

you can also write it as

```
select a.id from movies a join torrents b on a.movie_id = b.id
where b.seeds > 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to join the second table

```
 SELECT *  FROM movies as m INNER JOIN torrents as t ON m.id = t.movie
 WHERE t.seeds > 10
```